# Laravel - Upload project to server configurations error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I´m having a hard time putting my project on my domain, i´ve doing a lot of teste and none seems to work so i was hopping someone could help me, what i did so far was:

- I have created a subdomain, because i don´t want to mess with my main domain where i already have my main website.
- In the subdomain i have a wwwroot folder(public folder) where i have uploaded all the files from my project which i´m working locally.
- I have copied all the files from the public folder and putted them in the wwwroot and edited the index.php because of the lines related to the autoload.php and bootstrap(changing the path)
- I have configured the .env file with my domain specifications and gave permissions to write on the storage folder and vendor folder
- I have a problem because my cpanel doesn´t give me the ability to open a command terminal, so i cannot execute commands, i can only give permissions opening a lock symbol.

What am i missing here? i keep seeing a http 500 error...there are some other teste i have done but nothing works.

Regards

Comment: check if storage directory has write permission

Comment: can you post the env file

Comment: I have gave the storage folder permissions to write...and in the .env file as i said i have putted my server configurations, should i put anything else?

Comment: Check the basics. Did you run composer install? Do you have the .env file in the root folder? Did you copy .env file? Did you set a key with php artisan key:generate command?

Comment: Hi, my problem is, i have a windows server and i don´t have access to terminal, it´s a shared server...i have to search for another solution, thanks anyway